# how to sort map based on key length

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream

I have this map:

```
Map < String, String > unsortMap = new HashMap < String, String > ();
unsortMap.put("./cq:dialog/content/items/tabs/items/tab1/items/columns/items", "40");
unsortMap.put("./cq:dialog/content", "80");
unsortMap.put("./cq:dialog", "75");
unsortMap.put("./cq:dialog/content/items/tabs/items/tab2/items/columns/items", "40");
unsortMap.put("./cq:dialog/content/sling:resourcetype", "granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container");
```

I would like to sort it as based on the length of the key, for example if the key has less number of "/" then it will be the on top.

Expected output:

```
./cq:dialog
./cq:dialog/content/
./cq:dialog/content/sling:resourcetype
./cq:dialog/content/items/tabs/items/tab1/items/columns/items
./cq:dialog/content/items/tabs/items/tab2/items/columns/items
```

So for this, I write like this:

```
Map<String, String> sortedMap = unsortMap.entrySet().stream()
       .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

It does not give output as expected because it does not compare based on "/". I have tried custom comparator but could not get the expected result.

Comment: Do you only want to compare based on the length of the keys or the number of slashes the key contains? The question is a bit unclear.

Comment: How do you count for the use case-- *if the key has less number of "/" then it will be the on top*? Based on the accepted answer, it doesn' even match the requirements you've stated. Try to clarify what are you looking for.

Comment: Once you clarify that, do think of the use cases when you have two similar entries in terms of the count of `/` in them? e.g. `./cq:dialog/content/` and `./cq:dialog/content/sling:resourcetype` which goes first in the order?

Comment: @Naman, ./cq:dialog/content/ will go first in the order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To only compare the lengths, we can use `Integer.compare` in a custom Comparator. <sup>[Demo](https://ideone.com/r9SZ4O)</sup>

```
Map<String, String> sortedMap = unsortMap.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted((a, b) -> Integer.compare(a.getKey().length(), b.getKey().length()))
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Of course, you could also create a `TreeMap` with this custom Comparator so that new keys will still be ordered correctly.

```
final NavigableMap<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(
        (a, b) -> a.length() != b.length() ? Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length()) : a.compareTo(b));
sortedMap.putAll(unsortMap);
```

---

In order to compare the number of slashes, we can filter over the characters of both Strings.

```
final NavigableMap<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>((a, b) -> {
    final long slashes1 = a.chars().filter(c -> c == '/').count();
    final long slashes2 = b.chars().filter(c -> c == '/').count();
    return slashes1 != slashes2 ? Long.compare(slashes1, slashes2) : a.compareTo(b);
});
sortedMap.putAll(unsortMap);
```

As Andreas suggested, the comparator can be simplified using `.thenComparing`:

```
final NavigableMap<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(
        Comparator.comparingLong((String s) -> s.chars().filter(c -> c == '/').count())
         .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

Alternatively:

```
Map<String, String> sortedMap = unsortMap.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted((a, b) -> Long.compare(a.getKey().chars().filter(c->c=='/').count(), b.getKey().chars().filter(c->c=='/').count()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue,
                LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: how does this even solve *if the key has less number of "/" then it will be the on top*?

Comment: @Naman You're right. I misread the question. I'm going to edit.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing.  And yet it was accepted.  Perhaps the OP doesn't know what they want.

Comment: You could do it shorter using `new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingLong((String s) -> s.chars().filter(c -> c == '/').count()).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()))`

Comment: You actually need the `(String s)` part, because the inference engine cannot handle method chains, so it needs guidance.